# Eliminating $x,y,z$ from given set of equalities

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Given that: $x-2y+z=a$, $x^2-2y^2+z^2=b$, $x^3-2y^3+z^3=c$ and $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{2}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=0$. Eliminate $x,y,z$ from given set of equations. [Hint: Use $x^2+z^2=(x+z)^2-2xz$ and $x^3+z^3=(x+z)(x^2+z^2)-xz(x+z)$]

Now using hints as given, I can solve $y$ in terms of $a,b,c$, but now sure how to do it for $x,z$. So for example, for $y$:

$$\begin{aligned}b&=(x^2+z^2)-2y^2 \\ &=(x+z)^2-2xz-2y^2\\ &=(a+2y)^2-y(a+2y)-2y^2\end{aligned}$$

If we plug in the solution of $y$ from this into the third equation, one involving third powers of $x,y,z$, then we would be left with an expression only in $a,b,c$, but doing so is quite laborious. Is there any alternate method?

How to proceed? Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The relation you derived is linear in $y$. The rest is somewhat laborious, but not unworkable.

Comment: @dxiv True, but in an exam situation one would straight up assume there to be some neat trick available which simplifies work considerably. This 'brute force' method would straight up be eliminated for lack of ingenuity.

Answer (score 1):

We leave it to the OP to show that if $a = 0$ then $b = 0$ and $c =0$ and $x=y=z$.

Else

$\tag 1 \Large{y = \frac{b-a^2}{3a}}$

and by the 4th equation $b \ne a^2$.

and since

$x^3+z^3=(x+z)(x^2+z^2)-xz(x+z)= (x+z)\big((x+z)^2-2xz\big)-xz(x+z)$

and

$xz = \frac{1}{2} (x+z)y$

we have

$x^3+z^3= (x+z)\big((x+z)^2-(x+z)y\big)-\frac{1}{2} (x+z)y(x+z)$

and therefore

$c + 2y^3 = (x+z)\big((x+z)^2-(x+z)y\big)-\frac{1}{2} (x+z)y(x+z)$

And so

$\tag 2 c + 2y^3 = (a+2y)^3 - \frac{3}{2} (a+2y)^2 y$

---

**Work check**

Let $a = 1$ and $b = 4$ so that $y = 1$.

Solving $\text{(2)}$ we get $c = 11.5$

Returning to the original system we find

$x = \frac{1}{2}(3 + \sqrt3) \land z = \frac{1}{2} (3 - \sqrt3)$

or

$x = \frac{1}{2}(3 - \sqrt3) \land z = \frac{1}{2} (3 + \sqrt3)$

Comment: It seems unclear what you've done.  Eliminating $x, y, z$ is essentially establishing a relationship between $a, b, c$, like so: $13a^6+27a^2b^2=15a^4b+108a^3c+9b^3$, for $a\neq0$, and $a^2\neq \pm b$.  The OP is asking for a short way to do it, in the answer posted above, not sure if there is any way to do it, short or long.

Comment: @Macavity The answer to the contest question is (2) and if you want you can replace $y$ with its equivalent in (1).